# What's the title of the short story about wife accidentally eating all of her husband's food so she cooked "something" instead?

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I am not actually sure if this is a story I have watched, or read, or both. Certainly I have watched it as I have pictures on my mind. Anyway, the plot is: The wife is (I guess) abused by her husband. One day when he came back from work, he brought a meat (I don't remember what specifically) and it seems to be that this meat is her husband's favourite. After the wife cooked the food, she tried to taste or took a bite from the meat. The food was so delicious that she didn't notice that she has eaten all of the now-cooked meat. She panicked and rushed outside to think of a solution (for the husband has not yet arrived)

(this is the part where I am not sure)

So she goes outside and saw a funeral going on, with a body on a casket. After that she took home a meat, cooked it, and watched her husband eat someone's organ.

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! Are you certain that if this was written, it was a short story (in the literary sense?) If it was a short story, do you remember anything else about it - e.g. if it was in an anthology? See the [identification-request wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) for more kinds of useful information

Answer (score 6):

The story is almost certainly 'Just Delicious' as told in Scary Stories 3 'collected from Folklore and Retold by Alvin Schwartz' and can be found at [www.scaryforkids.com](https://www.scaryforkids.com/just-delicious/)

> After he left, Mina began to cook the liver. She added vegetables and spices and simmered it all afternoon, just the way George liked it. When she thought it was done, she cut off a small piece and tasted it. It was delicious, the best she had ever made. She ate a second piece. Then a third. It was so good, she could not stop eating it. It was only when the liver was all gone that she thought of George. He would be coming home soon. What would he do when he found that she had eaten all of the liver? Some men would laugh - but not George. He would be angry and mean, and she did not want to face that again. But where could she get another piece of liver that late in the day. Then she remembered the old woman lying in the church next door waiting to be buried....

Kudos to you for mentioning 'organs', I assumed 'liver' which made it very easy to find.